# Struggling with changing the context in a loop and assigning the value to object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am looping over the object and I want to change the original "this" object values dynamically. problem is that I am getting undefined when I try to change "this" context. here is my code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ah such a goofball I am ....
got it working

all I needed to do was
before each I am adding
var object2 = this;
then in each loop just do this
object2[key] = object[key]

and that worked.

thanks